# "Precognitive" badge

Tags: discussion, badges, feature-request

The [Precognitive](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/892/precognitive) badge has been awarded 0 times. Why?

```
"Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase."
```

Because obviously no one followed the Area51 proposal of StackOverflow. And nobody ever will, because StackOverflow is already way past the commitment phase.

So we might as well get rid of this badge, am I right?

Comment: See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71712/should-the-precognitive-badge-be-listed-in-the-list-of-sofu-badges): `The Precognitive badge appears in the badge list on every site to announce the presence of Area 51, and its primary function.`